# Numpy with PyPy problems

Tags: numpy, python-c-api, pypy

I'm trying to install numpy and other packages with PyPy. I get the error: "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/"

I used "pypy3 -m pip install numpy" in cmd.

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, but it didn't help.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the problem is really PyPy, it might just be that you cannot compile any source package on your machine (someone reported that problem on the [pypy issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/3056/numpy-installation-fails-on-windows) but it turns out not to be a PyPy-specific problem)

Can you use your build environment? You should have a start menu item about "VS2019 ... Command Prompt", and after opening that you should be able to run the compiler `cl /?`. If you cannot run the compiler you may have installed the tools without actually installing a c/c++ compiler.

Can you create a virtualenv with cpython3.6 (not PyPy) and make sure `pip install --force-reinstall --no-binary :all: numpy==1.17.0` works on cpython3.6 on your machine?

Does `pip install --upgrade setuptools` change anything?

Can you install something else that should build a c-extension module, like lxml (`pip install --force-reinstall --no-binary :all: lxml`)?

Comment: the --no-binary option does not change anything, a 6 GB installation of visual studio c build tools is required compulsory !!!  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/